# Do not allow Interaction with page when ajax call is running

Tags: jquery

Here is my jQuery code

```
<div id="loading" class = "loading">
  <p><img src="../images/ajax-loader.gif" /> Please Wait</p>
</div>
<%@include file="footer.jsp" %>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$(function(){
    $("#loading").hide();
    $("#loading").ajaxStart(function(){ 
        $(this).show();
     }).ajaxStop(function(){
         $(this).hide();
     });
});
```

Whenever any Ajax call runs on the page the image loading please wait is displayed

I do not want the user to interact with page at that time. How can i do that ?

Also please suggest some css which will make my loading image over jsp page (using z-index or something).

Thanks !

Comment: create an overlay effect .

Comment: What you are already doing will work, though keep in mind .ajaxStart can only be called on `document` as of jQuery 1.8, not your loader. Just make your loading div covers the entire website.

Comment: There are many options out there.  What you want is the loading div to be a modal.  If you google modal overlay you'll find a lot of solutions.  One that I use a lot is the jqueryui dialog.  Which has a modal option.

Answer (score 2):

Try the BlockUI plugin for the overlay: http://malsup.com/jquery/block/

Usage:

```
$(document).ajaxStart($.blockUI).ajaxStop($.unblockUI);
```

Answer (score 1):

Set `async: false` in your AJAX properties.